# How to understand Spring @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm following a tutorial about Spring MVC and I cannot understand something about the `@ComponentScan` annotation even after reading the spring API doc, so here is the sample code:

**Configuring View Controllers**

```
package com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
// Other imports ommitted
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web" })
public class WebMvcContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // Other methods ommitted
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index.htm").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

**Annotation-based Controllers**

```
package com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;    
@Controller    
public class IndexController {    
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm")    
    public ModelAndView indexPage() {     
        return new ModelAndView("index");    
    }    
}
```

My question is, for View Controllers, by adding `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web" })`, what will be done in the background? Will the package `com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web` offer something for these view controllers?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simply put - `@ComponentScan` tells Spring in which packages you have annotated classes which should be managed by Spring. So, for example, if you have a class annotated with `@Controller` which is in a package which is not scanned by Spring, you will not be able to use it as Spring controller.

Classes annotated with `@Configuration` is a *new* way of configuring Spring using annotations instead of XML files (it's called Java configuration). Spring needs to know which packages contain spring beans, otherwise you would have to register each bean individually. That's what `@ComponentScan` is used for.

In your example, you tell Spring that package `com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web` contains classes which should be handled by Spring. Spring then finds a class annotated with `@Controller`, and processes it, which results in all requests coming to `/index.htm` being intercepted by the controller.

When the request is intercepted, Spring needs to know what response to send to the caller. Since you return an instance of `ModelAndView`, it will try to find a view (JSP page) called `index` in your project (details of this depend on configured view resolvers), and renders it to the user.

If `@Controller` annotation wasn't present, or that package wasn't scanned by Spring, all of this would not be possible.

Comment: so for my example, what if I delete @ComponentScan(), will my program not work anymore because he is lack of some beans or something else?

Comment: Yes, your `IndexController` will not be functional.

Comment: It seems more clear than just now but not 100%. May I ask you to explain the relationship between these two class? How do the view, the "/index.htm" and controller be connected.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it is still not clear for you, I suggest you look for answers in Spring documentation.

Comment: If I specify a package in `basePackages=...`, will it scan just the classes in that package, or will it scan sub-packages, too?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz It will scan sub-packages too.