# Spring boot and Spring data no bean found entityMangerFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've got a Spring boot application with enabled autoconfiguration. 
My application is divided into 4 modules core, model, rest and repository.
Repository module uses Spring data and Hibernate. It is a module that contains all class entities and all spring data repositories.

The problem is that my application cannot find EntityManagerFactory that to my mind should be created by autoconfiguration based on added Hibernate dependency.

What error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

here is my main gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.1.0.RELEASE"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.9'
}

group 'com.wat'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
    compile project(':model')
    compile project(':rest')
    compile project(':repository')

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'

    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final"
    apt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'

        compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final"
        compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final"
    }
}
```

my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My repository module gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.7.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13'

    compile project(":model")
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

and my repository module configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.wat.zpm.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

}
```

According to what I found out is that spring autoconfigurer automatically creates bean EntityManagerFactory based on classpath classes so everything should work fine with given annotations.

What is more autoconfiguration logging says that `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` was matched.

The class that misses the EntityManagerFactory:

```
@Repository
    public class UserRepositoryServiceImpl implements UserRepositoryService {

        private final UserEntityMapper userMapper;
        private final UserRepository userRepository;

        public UserRepositoryServiceImpl(UserEntityMapper userMapper, UserRepository userRepository1) {
            this.userMapper = userMapper;
            this.userRepository = userRepository1;
        }
    }
```

`UserRepository` is a interface that extends `JpaRepository`

I've made a research and couldn't found annotation or dependency that my project could possibly miss.

Comment: Maybe you should use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead of `spring-data-jpa`?

Comment: I think in `RepositoryConfiguration` class you needto use `@ComponantScan` annotation !

Comment: Right the problem was missing `@ComponentScan` annotation.  @AvijitBarua could you elaborate why this was an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@ComponantScan` in `RepositoryConfiguration` class.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963639/how-to-understand-spring-componentscan) is the great explanation of componentscan annotation.