# Using .getBean() on a @Repository class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm currently learning Spring and Hibernate. I have a StudentDAOImpl class that contains all my database queries. I want to get an instance of this bean in my main function and run the query methods there all in my main function for testing. I'm trying to do this by calling the getBean() method because the name of the bean is the class but first letter is lowercase if I'm not mistaken. The compiler is giving me this error

```
Exception in thread "main org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'studentDAOImpl' available**
```

Why can't Spring find my StudentDAOImpl bean? Thank you for your time in reading this post.
Here's my code

Main Function

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnimalConfig.class,HibernateConfig.class); // Makes the sessionFactory bean known to the IOC
        StudentDAOImpl student = (StudentDAOImpl)ctx.getBean("studentDAOImpl");
        Student aStudent = new Student("dasdasdas","dasdadas","dsadasdasda@gmail.com");
        student.addStudent(aStudent);
    
        (( ConfigurableApplicationContext )ctx).close();  //Close the applicationContext
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);    

    }
```

StudentDAOImpl Class

```
@Repository  //Sets up componenent scanning for DI for our services
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    //Queries Ommited from post for space saving purposes
}
```

HibernateConfiguration File

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
@Scope("singleton")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan());
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("danielL45");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
      = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

private String[] packagesToScan(){
  return new String[] {
    "com.example.demo.Entities.Student"
  };
}
private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread");
    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the component scanning happening? Or is that the problem ?

Comment: Doesn't @Repository trigger the registering of StudentDAOImpl?

Comment: It identifies the class as a Spring component.  But you also  need to do a component scan so spring can know where to look for the components, it doesn’t know where the components are otherwise.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28963639/217324

Comment: I see. Thank you for the forwarded resource link. I appreciate and will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`StudentDAOImpl student = ctx.getBean(StudentDAOImpl.class)`

This is a more secure way to get the bean that we need, since we may have **only one** bean with this class, using a string to select a Spring Bean has a propability of not working when not writing the name correctly.

Comment: Please consider providing some details as to why OP is having the issue and how this solves it.